# SQLDataReader Row Count

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatareader

I am trying to get the number of rows that were returned by iterating the reader. But I always get 1 when I run this code? Did I screw up something in this?

```
int count = 0;
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        count++;
        rep.DataSource = reader;
        rep.DataBind();
    }
}
resultsnolabel.Text += " " + String.Format("{0}", count) + " Results";
```

Comment: What is `rep` variable?

Comment: Please note `HasRows` is useful for those of us who just want to distinguish between 1 or more rows (`HasRows==true`) and 0 zero rows (`HasRows == false`), [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12609979/1175496)
`HasRows | Type: System.Boolean true if the SqlDataReader contains one or more rows; otherwise false.`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

SQLDataReaders are forward-only. You're essentially doing this:

```
count++;  // initially 1
.DataBind(); //consuming all the records

//next iteration on
.Read()
//we've now come to end of resultset, thanks to the DataBind()
//count is still 1
```

You could do this instead:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    rep.DataSource = reader;
    rep.DataBind();
}
int count = rep.Items.Count; //somehow count the num rows/items `rep` has.
```

Comment: `rep` what type of variable is?

Comment: I think rep is a GridView

Answer (score 36):

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Load(reader);
 int numRows= dt.Rows.Count;
```

Comment: Nice solution, but the .Load method consume the Reader (as obvius). For evryone that is looking for a method to count record without consuming the Reader (like create a counter in an existing portion of code)  i'll save some time. It's simply not possible. You have to change the code and use DataTable.

Answer (score 13):

This will get you the row count, but will leave the data reader at the end.

```
dataReader.Cast<object>().Count();
```

Comment: Are you saying the data reader can still be used at the end of this to iterate and load the actual data _after_ having obtained a record count?

Answer (score -9):

Maybe you can try this: though please note - This pulls the column count, not the row count

```
 using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
 {
     while (reader.Read())
     {
         int count = reader.VisibleFieldCount;
         Console.WriteLine(count);
     }
 }
```