# How to check if SQLDataReader has no rows

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I am trying to figure out how to check if my `SqlDataReader` is null or has no rows (meaning the reservation does not exist) and then display a messagebox. For some reason when I debug once it hits the `While dr.Read())` code it steps out if it does not have a return result.

I've tried putting this code in a few different locations but none seem to fire off the messagebox if no records are returned

```
if (dr.GetValue(0) == DBNull.Value || !dr.HasRows)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Reservation Number Does Not Exist","Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
}
else
{
    (read records)
}
```

My code...

```
try
{
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   {
      using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
      {
         con.Open();
         cmd.CommandText = "usp_StoredProcedureName";
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regnum", regnumber);

         using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
             //Loop through all the rows, retrieving the columns you need.
             while (dr.Read())
             {
                 lblConf.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                 lblName.Text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString() + "," + dr.GetValue(2);
                 lblCompany.Text = dr.GetValue(3).ToString();
                 lblStatus.Text = dr.GetValue(4).ToString();
             }
         }
      }
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection! ");
}
```

Comment: Keep your loop the way it is but wrap an If Statement around it to check if (dr.HasRows){}

Comment: Nope, my SqlDataReader has "HasRows" set to true... but no rows were actually loaded in.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
if(dr.HasRows)
{
    // ....
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Reservation Number Does Not Exist","Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
}
```

[SqlDataReader.HasRows Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows.aspx)

Comment: Thanks this worked I was using the hasrows property just using it wrong I guess.

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your code to check:

```
sqlCommand cmd = new sqlCommand();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if(dr.HasRows)
{
    while(dr.Read())
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[The `HasRows` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows.aspx) may help you.

> Property Value
>
> Type: System.Boolean true if the SqlDataReader contains one or more
>   rows; otherwise false.

Answer (score 1):

> For some reason when I debug once it hits the `while dr.Read()` Code it steps out if it does not have a return result

I think what you're seeing here is that `SQLDataReader.Read()` returns `false` if there is not a next, or in this case a first record to read.

As others have responded, use the `HasRows` property to determine if you have any rows in the result set. Depending on what you need to accomplish, you may want to take advantage of the fact that `Read()` indeed returns `false` the first time its called for an empty result set.