# Input string was not in a correct format c# and asp.net

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm working on a simple asp.net log in page. a simple code when user log in it verifies with the sql and direct to the page for either staff or admin. but i have this error (int.Parse(myReader.ToString()) > 0) ... Input string was not in a correct format
my code..

```
string Connection = "Data Source=(ip);Initial Catalog=..;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=(id);Password=(pass)";
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(Connection);

SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from tar_login where Username ='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "' and Position='" + ddlPosition.Text + "';", myConn);

myConn.Open();

var myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
myConn.Close();

if (myReader != null)
{
    if (int.Parse(myReader.ToString()) > 0)
    {
        if (ddlPosition.Text == "Admin")
        {
            Response.Redirect("manager.aspx");
        }
    }
}

if (myReader != null)
{
    if (int.Parse(myReader.ToString()) > 0)
    {
        if (ddlPosition.Text == "Staff")
        {
            Response.Redirect("staff.aspx");
        }
    }
}

else
{
    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    Label1.Text = "Incorrect. Please try again";
    myConn.Close();
}
```

.help as im new to asp.net and c#

Comment: it means that `myReader.ToString()` was not a number, or not in a format that is an int.

Comment: debug your code, add a breakpoint at `var myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar();` and check what's it's value, may be not integer or null

Comment: @Noctis at break point i get myReader is null

Answer (score 0):

The `ExecuteScalar` returns an object (the row), or null.
Then you try to `ToString` it. Unless you return only one column, which is an int, this will not be something that `int.Parse` will be able to parse.

You can try `int.TryParse`, but it'll return false I believe. 
What do you have in `myReader` if you put a breakpoint in there? it might give you/us a better understanding about what you're dealing with.

---

Edit:

o_O ?!

You have two clauses saying : `if (myReader != null)`. Merge them.

Whenever you work with DB's or any resource you need to handle, use `using`, like **Saunders** suggested.

Other than that, you answered your question. If you get a `null` back, it cannot be parsed into an `int`.

You'll have to figure out your DB issues or your query, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

**Your ExecuteScalar() is bringing a non-numeric character (e.g. 'A'), which cannot be converted to integer.**

It seems in your code there is no need of checking > 0.

myReader != null is sufficient.

Whatever Samiey has suggested above looks perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
    string Connection = "Data Source=(ip);Initial Catalog=..;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=(id);Password=(pass)";
    SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(Connection);

    SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from tar_login where Username ='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "' and Position='" + ddlPosition.Text + "';", myConn);

    myConn.Open();

    Sqldatareader myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
    myConn.Close();

     if (reader.HasRows)
        {
if (ddlPosition.Text == "Admin")
        {
            Response.Redirect("manager.aspx");
        }
else if (ddlPosition.Text == "Staff")
        {
            Response.Redirect("staff.aspx");
        }
    else
    {
        Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        Label1.Text = "Incorrect. Please try again";
        myConn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: hi, i tried ur code but i got a squiggly line underneath HasRows. and when i put my cursor over it, i got this error:  'object' does not contain a definition for 'HasRows' and no extension of method 'HasRows' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609959/how-to-check-if-sqldatareader-has-no-rows Check the link for checking datareader has rows or not