# C# SQL Query returning different results than Management Studio using the same query

Tags: c#, sql

An `SQL` query that I'm executing from my application is returning different results than SQL Management Studio, specifically missing entire rows of data.

I've tried stripping the query way down to just "`SELECT *`" from the relevant table with a single WHERE clause, this achieved the same result of the `C#` version missing the same row each time.

A stripped down `SQL` query (that still has the issue) looks like this

```
SELECT Token, Last_update, repeatno, Maxrepeatno, Dispwindowstart
FROM v_eps_prescriptions
WHERE Token='F69F4D-C82043-70379I'
```

The `C#` version is

```cs
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
$@"SELECT Token, Last_update, messages, repeatno, Maxrepeatno
FROM v_eps_prescriptions
WHERE Token='{UUID}'",
conn);
```

The `SQL` version for this query will return 2 rows, `C#` will only return 1 row.

I've been putting the data into a dataGridView to debug which is where I'm seeing just the single row.

**Edit:**
As requested the full chunk of C# that performs the query and what outputs to a datagrid (which is temporary for debugging)

```
try
{
    conn.ConnectionString = $"Data Source=[source];Initial Catalog=[Cat];Integrated Security=True";
    conn.Open();

    foreach (string UUID in ValidUUIDList)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
            DateTime dtpast = dt.AddMonths(-6);

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(string.Format($@"SELECT Token, Last_update, messages, repeatno, Maxrepeatno
                                                                FROM [Table]
                                                                WHERE Token='{UUID}'
                                                                AND Dispwindowstart
                                                                BETWEEN '{dtpast.ToString("yyyy - MM - dd")} 00:00:00.000'
                                                                AND '{dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")} 00:00:00.000'
                                                                OR Token='{UUID}'
                                                                AND Dispwindowstart IS NULL"),
                                                                    conn);

            using (SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataTable.Load(dataReader);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"An error occured while processing UUID {UUID}. \n\n{err.Message}");
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"An error occured while connecting to the Nexphase database. \n\n{err.Message}");
}
```

Comment: Use the SQL Profiler and see what SQL query is generated when the C# version runs.

Comment: @Thangadurai the query is correct, I've stepped through the code and taken the parsed query from the debugger and put that into the sql studio to work backwards and got the same result of 2 rows in sql and 1 with c#

Comment: Check the `Database` names. both are connected to Same DB?

Comment: @ShyamVemula both are the same yes, the destination only has one db

Comment: Where are you seeing 1 row? in the grid view? There's a whole lot of code between what you've posted and grid view. Can you post the code that runs the command and also debug the returned dataset and see if you can get a count

Comment: Here's a whole bunch of suggestions for getting a rowcount https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502863/sqldatareader-row-count/14629894

Comment: Can you post the c# code where you read the results?

Comment: What is the type of `Token`? is it `nvarchar-something`? or `uniqueidentifier`? `uniqueidentifier` has very specific formatting rules (there are lots of ways of representing a UUID), and comparing a `uniqueidentifier` via a string can get hairy.  If it is `uniqueidentifier`: does it work if you use an ADO.NET parameter with the value from a `Guid`? alternatively: what is the exact `CommandText` after your `$@"..."` token replacement has happened?

Comment: @HansKilian Code has been edited into original post

Comment: @MarcGravell the Token isnt a unique field, multiple rows contain the same string which is what i want to return

Comment: I would obfuscate sensitive data in your code btw. You have a partially qualified domain name, and database name in there

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Code has been edited into original post

Comment: Do what @Thangadurai suggested. Attach Sql Profiler and capture the query that is sent with the parameters. You can copy/paste this into SSMS and execute it which should then easily show you why/where the differences are occurring.

Comment: @MatthewEvans thanks, i knew i would forget to do that even after reminding myself too...

Comment: Try using `if (dataReader.HasRows)` rather than `if (dataReader.Read())`. I suspect Read removes the first row from the result set.

Comment: @HansKilian that nailed it, thats now returning all the rows i want (how frustrating that its just that) However now the datatable is closing the reader?

Comment: SqlDataReader is  a forward-only stream, so when `Load` reads through it, there's no way to get back to the beginning.

Comment: @HansKilian ok sure, i can work with this, i'm loading the data into the datagrid (might swap this to a dataset) so ill work from that instead of the reader, which i think is the more accepted protocol anyway?